# How to show that the function $f(x) = \sin x + \tan x$ on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ has an inverse

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Given that $f(x)=\sin x+\tan x$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Show that it has an inverse function.  Find the derivative of the inverse of $f(x)$ at $x=0$.

What is the appropriate way to show that a function has an inverse?
How can I inverse two trigonometric function so I can derive them when they are tied up each other with sum symbol?

Comment: Welcome to this site. What are the conditions necessary for a function to have an inverse? Heard of bijectivity? For the second part, use the inverse function theorem (which is basically chain rule).

Comment: In order for a function to have an inverse, the only thing one need is the function is injective. If  the function is injective, then it has an inverse over its  range. Since both $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ is strictly increasing over $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$, ....

Comment: @achille hui I think that we need not only injection but bijection to have an inverse for a function.

Comment: @hamzaboulahia Injection is sufficient.

Comment: @hamzaboulahia you need bijection only when you want the domain of your inverse equals to the whole set that your function can take values.

Comment: Yes, and that's right and we want the inverse function to be defined on the given interval so it needs to be bijective.

Comment: @hamzaboulahia No, an extension of $f(x)$ or the domain of $f(x)$ in general is $\mathbb R$. A subset of it is the given domain of the exercise, thus $"1-1"$ is enough. Also this is a standard pre-calculus/calculus class, perplexating such details will hinder the OPs chances of a correct understanding for his leve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show that this function has an inverse, you need to prove that it's "$1-1$", thus meaning that the given functional (function in our simple case) is injective.

But, $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ are strictly increasing over $\left( -\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. This means that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing which implies that $f(x)$ is also "$1-1"$ $\implies$ $f$ can be inversed.

Now, the expression of $f$ cannot be inversed explicitly (or to put it better, it can be, but it's impossible to be carried out by hand).

But, consider the following standard Theorem proved in pre-calculus courses :

> **Theorem :** Suppose that $f$ has an inverse function $f^{-1}$. If $f$ is differentiable at $f^{-1}$ and $f '(f^{-1}(x))$ is not equal to zero, then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $x$ and the following differentiation formula holds :
>   $$(f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$
>   **Proof :**
>
> Let $y_0\in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\exists x_0\in\mathbb{R} : f(x_0)=y_0$. Then $x\to x_0 \implies y=f(x)\to f(x_0)=y_0$.
>   By definition, it is :
>   $$(f^{-1})'(y_0)=\lim_{y\rightarrow y_0}\frac{f^{-1}(y)-f^{-1}(y_0)}{y-y_0}=\lim_{y\rightarrow y_0}\frac{f^{-1}(f(x))-f^{-1}(f(x_0))}{f(x)-f(x_0)}\\=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{x-x_0}{f(x)-f(x_0)}=\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(y_0))}$$

Can you now use that theorem to find the derivative of the inverse at $x=0$ ?

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to prove that if a function has an inverse. So, Here is my solution;
The inverse of it is x=siny+tany and x is 0. So -tany=siny, therefore cosy=-1 and y is π at the given point. The only thing left is to derive the f(x) and put π in it right?

Comment: Your elaboration in terms of explaining is very complicated and hard to follow. Maybe you would like to typeset using MathJax? By the way if an answer was helpful you may use the vote up button and the answer that fits you the best may be marked as accepted using the tick marker.

Comment: I do not know how to use a typeset yet.
What i did was just inversing f(x)
f(x)=y we can describe it like that. To inverse i just changed x's with y's so function becomes like this one below:
x=siny+tany, due to the question we are at the point x=0, so equation becomes 0=siny+tany. After solving it I figure that y is equal to π at the point x=0. Finally I used the theorem to solve it. Did I do it right? If not, Where was i wrong?

Comment: What you did is wrong. For $x=0$, it is : $f(0) = 0$. This means that $f^{-1}(0) = 0$. Can you now continue to calculate $(f^{-1})'(0)$ ?

Comment: Okay now i understand my mistake and the right path to follow thank you for your time ^^

Comment: @HouseBT Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

$\star$For a real function such as the given function $f$. To show that $d$ has an inverse function, you have to show that $f$ is strictly monotonic on the given interval $]-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}[$.

$\star$ For the second question, you don't have to calculate the inverse the each function to find the inverse of of $f$ because; If $f=g+h$ then, $$ f^{-1}\neq g^{-1}+h^{-1}$$
But then again, you are only asked to calculate the inverse at a certain point $x=0$. So you can use the formula $$ (f^{-1})'(x)=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$